# Tagedit with autocomplete from mysql

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tag-it

I'm looking for a good simple way to select multiple data within one input field, which is submitting the ID's and get data from a mysql Database

Allready found some tag editors, but none of them with

```
sending ID
autocomplete
data from mysql
```

Something that way:
http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/playground.html

Problem in this case is, the autocomplete is fully listed within `autocomplete.php`, not that bad but if you have 10000 db entries it's getting slow

Other solution would maybe
http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html
but I found no way submitting ID's and getting autocomplete from mysql db

If there is a way, getting this with id:
http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Without bootstrap that would be great

Any help?

Comment: Have you seen select2 [https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple). It supports ajax request [https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)?

Comment: yes, i saw that, but could not find the option to return id or submit id

Comment: Well, look here [https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags). Now, if you open browser console and type `$(".js-example-tags").select2("data")`, you get array of objects, where you can find id [http://i.stack.imgur.com/TbXN0.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TbXN0.png)

Comment: ahhh there it is ;) thank you